# C# library for bounds based geometry search

Tags: c#, .net, extents, spatial-index, library

I am searching for C# library which has code that builds spatial index in memory based on geometry bounds and enables fast searching for all geometry inside given bounds.

I prefer free library.

Comment: http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/ but you say where your source data is coming from MYSQL? POSTGRES, SQLSERVER, ORACLE? or file

Comment: I have many data sources, so I will look for most generic solution from suggestions all gave.

Comment: I was looking for C# bindings for [libspatialindex](http://libspatialindex.github.com/), but I currently don't see anything beyond [Rtree](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/) for Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a C#/.NET port of JTS Topology Suite: https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite

Here's the index classes:
https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/tree/develop/NetTopologySuite/Index

***License Information:***
NTS: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/develop/License.md

EDL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/locationtech/jts/master/LICENSE_EDLv1.txt

EPL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/locationtech/jts/master/LICENSE_EPLv1.txt

Comment: This looks OK, I will try to use this code and check this as answer if there is no problems.

Comment: Using 1.11 version, looks OK for now.

Comment: Beware. JTS is licensed under LGPL, which means you'll have to disclose the source code of your main application using it.

Comment: @matrixugly: it's dual licensed under EPL and EDL.

Comment: Ah - right. I see this from the JTS wikipedia page. "up to JTS 1.14, and the GEOS port, are published under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL)."

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try googling for specific indexing methods.  For example, when I Google for `C# r-tree` [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cspatialindexrt/) is the first result.

Comment: Of course my life would have been more simple in start if I knew that I was looking for R-Tree ;) Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use SQLite + Spatialite in memory. Create a table with a geometry column and a spatial index and insert your geometries there. Then use SQL queries to get the matching geometries.